# Narrow Type Conversion Safety

Tags: c++, types, casting

If source holds smaller value than destination type, 
narrowing conversion in c++ is safe?

For example, I am casting a 8 byte data type (Source) to 4 byte data type(Destination). I know that Sourcedoes not contain a value greater than 4 bytes. So this conversion will always be safe?

Comment: Assuming we're talking about built-in types here, then it's always safe if the value is representable in the output type.

Comment: not really, you could lost information since byte 5

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ "if the value is representable in the output type". Which means there is *no* information in byte 5

Comment: Yes, I am talking about build in type.

Comment: @Angew, I agree, therefore I wrote could, if the source data can fit in a destination type then ever. will be fine... too risky if not validated in advance....

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ But My source data is only four bytes.